# Type-stability in Julia's product iterator

Tags: julia, type-stability

I am trying to make `A` in the following code type-stable.

```
using Primes: factor

function f(n::T, p::T, k::T) where {T<:Integer}
    return rand(T, n * p^k)
end

function g(m::T, n::T) where {T<:Integer}
    
    i = 0
    for A in Iterators.product((f(n, p, T(k)) for (p, k) in factor(m))...)
        i = sum(A)
    end
    return i

end
```

Note that `f` is type-stable.  The variable `A` is not type-stable because the product iterator will return different sized tuples depending on the values of `n` and `m`.  If there was an iterator like the product iterator that returned a Vector instead of a Tuple, I believe that the type-instability would go away.

Does anyone have any suggestions to make `A` type-stable in the above code?

Edit:  I should add that `f` returns a variable-sized Vector of type `T`.

One way I have solved the type-stability is by doing this.

```
function g(m::T, n::T) where {T<:Integer}
    B = Vector{T}[T[]]
    for (p, k) in factor(m)
        C = Vector{T}[]
        for (b, r) in Iterators.product(B, f(n, p, T(k)))
            c = copy(b)
            push!(c, r)
            push!(C, c)
        end
        B = C
    end

    for A in B
        i = sum(A)
    end

    return i
end
```

This (and in particular, `A`) is now type-stable, but at the cost lots of memory.  I'm not sure of a better way to do this.

Comment: Where does the `T` come from in the definition of `f(n, p, k) = T[ #... ]` If it's a global (non-const) variable, then this won't be type stable. Also, can you make your example runnable? It is difficult to understand the problem with crucial bits missing.

Comment: Your recent edit doesn't really clear up anything. `f` is still apparently using a type variable `T`, which comes out of nowhere. Is it intended to be some sort of pseudo-code and indicate that the vector will have eltype `T`? The `T` really confuses the issue, can't you just write an actual runnable function `f`? It's much easier if you provide code that *really* runs and really demonstrates your issue.

Comment: My edits weren't finished before your second comment.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use this file on Github, which is the full code.  https://github.com/byhill/ModularSquareRoots.jl/blob/main/src/ModularSquareRoots.jl

Comment: Is `sqrtmodp` type-stable? (my guess is the function in the question calls it in some execution flows)

Comment: I'm almost certain it is.  I checked it with @code_warntype with many different types of inputs.

Comment: The @code_warntype only flags the variable `A` when using it on `f` (or in my repository, `sqrtmod`).  And my "fix" above removes the type instability at the cost of allocating tons of memory.

Comment: Splatting dynamically sized containers will be slow. Some sort of looping seems more likely to get you performance. But your looping code seems to create a lot of temporary arrays. Is the array `B` always a vector of single-element vectors?

Comment: The array `B`, once finished, would be filled with vectors of size x, where x is the number of prime factors of `m`.  The elements in `B` contain each "product", so to speak, if that makes sense.  I'm unsure how to go about this without using the splat operator or using my memory intensive fix, without fully reimplementing `product`.

Comment: Are you really only interested in the sum over the elements? Because then you don't need to keep all the arrays around, but should instead make sure to accumulate the final output sum as you go. (Another thing to point out is that you are only returning the sum over the last element of B which means that you only need the last element of each random vector. Did you perhaps intend to do `i += sum(A)`)?

Comment: Currently, you can replace `g` with: `g(m, n) = sum(last(f(n, p, k)) for (p, k) in factor(m))`, which is of, course, much faster.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it is more than just a sum I'm doing.  But your answer is a good solution, so thank you!

Comment: Even if it isn't just a sum, if it is a *reduction*, where you extract a single number from your data, you should try to do that reduction aggressively instead of accumulating arrays that you only later reduce. (This is general advice, not necessarily relevant to the accepted solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to get this completely type stable, but you can isolate the type instability with a function barrier. Convert the factorization to a tuple in an outer function, which you pass to an inner function which is type stable. This gives just one dynamic dispatch, instead of many:

```
# inner, type stable
function _g(n, tup)
    i = 0
    for A in Iterators.product((f(n, p, k) for (p, k) in tup)...)
        i += sum(A)  # or i = sum(A), whatever
    end
    return i
end

# outer function
g(m::T, n::T) where {T<:Integer} = _g(n, Tuple(factor(m)))
```

Some benchmarks:

```
julia> @btime g(7, 210);  # OP version
  149.600 μs (7356 allocations: 172.62 KiB)

julia> @btime g(7, 210);  # my version
  1.140 μs (6 allocations: 11.91 KiB)
```

You should expect to hit compilation occasionally, whenever you get a number that contains a new number of factors.